# How to display current values in inputs when editing forms with react/redux

Tags: reactjs, mongoose, redux

I am pulling data from a an instance of MongoDB (mLab).

When I go to edit an item I want the current item's value (data which is already in my redux store before this component is loaded) to display on the Input here:

[image: picture]

I've tested setting the state of my component to something such as ```state = { name: this.props.item.name || "" }``

That's about it. I figured if I had the value loaded as state on render the input's value would appear there.

```
import _ from "lodash";
import React from "react";
import InputField from "components/inputs/InputField";
import { withRouter, Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { editExercise } from "actions/exerciseActions";

class ExerciseEdit extends React.Component {
  state = { name: "" };

  onChange = e => {
    this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  };

  onSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const { history } = this.props;
    const { id, exerciseId } = this.props.match.params;
    const exerciseProps = { ...this.state };

    console.log(this.props.match.params);

    this.props.editExercise(id, exerciseId, exerciseProps, history);
  };

  render() {
    const { errors } = this.props;
    return (
      <div>
        <h1 className="title is-3">Edit your exercise</h1>
        <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
          <InputField
            label="Name"
            name="name"
            type="text"
            value={this.state.name}
            onChange={this.onChange}
            errors={errors}
          />
          <Link
            to={`/workouts/${this.props.match.params.id}`}
            className="button is-danger is-large"
            style={{ marginTop: "20px" }}
          >
            Cancel
          </Link>
          <button
            type="submit"
            className="button is-primary is-large"
            style={{ marginTop: "20px" }}
          >
            Submit
          </button>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = ({ workouts }) => {
  return { workouts };
};

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  { editExercise }
)(withRouter(ExerciseEdit));
```

I expect to see my Input containing the current item's name value, that way the user is able to see it's current value before editing.

Comment: Why don't you move state of ExerciseEdit to redux store?

Comment: Wouldn't I then have to call an action creator on every keystroke then to update my store with the inputs value? Or do you mean storing the final value in my store? The values I am using I can get from data from my MongoDB.

Comment: Yes, I mean removing the state completely. It doesn't sound good at first look. but you will have the power to do anything! One single source of truth.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `componentWillReceiveProps` component lifecycle. Like this

```
class ExerciseEdit extends React.Component {
    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
        if (nextProps.item.name) {
           this.setState({ name: nextProps.item.name })
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Appreciate the help,but that did nothing for me.

Answer (score 0):

I got what I wanted in regards to my input displaying the current values pulled from a DB when editing a form.

What I did was basically used a smaller library than redux-form called Formik.

To me, this was the simplest solution as it solved my issue very easily and painlessly, which so far in my journey as a developer has seemed to be the best thing I can do for myself.

If anyone else wants to persist values when editing a form, check out Formik, their docs are straight forward and very detailed.

Thanks for the help everyone who commented.